# Spring web app to facebook access info

Tags: java, facebook, spring

I'm trying to follow the tutorial https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-facebook/. I made correct facebook app ID. But as soon as I launch the app, I got following.

[image]

So what could be wrong? Please advice me. Note that I didn't add/remove any code from the example except in `src/main/resources/application.properties  spring.social.facebook.appId` and `spring.social.facebook.appSecret`.

Answer (score 0):

Go to facebook and there Developer -> My Apps -> Your app name --> Setting 
see the "Secure Canvas URL". Make sure it is same as the URL of the your application. If you are connecting to localhost , make sure on FB it points 
to localhost.